# MySQL index is not used when using SELECT ALL for binary lower

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a `keywords` table like this:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| country | varchar(2)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I have compound index on `[name, country]`:

```
+----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name                           | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type |
+----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
| keywords |          0 | PRIMARY                            |            1 | id          | A         |      377729 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |
| keywords |          1 | index_keywords_on_name_and_country |            1 | name        | A         |      377729 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
| keywords |          1 | index_keywords_on_name_and_country |            2 | country     | A         |      377729 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |
+----------+------------+------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
```

I need to use `BINARY LOWER` to compare the `name` field, so my query will be like this:

```
SELECT keywords.* FROM `keywords` WHERE (BINARY LOWER(`name`) = BINARY LOWER('Apple') AND `country` = 'US');
```

But the problem is: it's not using the index. Using the `Explain` I have:

```
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | keywords | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 366519 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

However, instead of `select *`, if I select some fields, it will then use index:

```
Explain SELECT keywords.id, keywords.name FROM `keywords` WHERE (BINARY LOWER(`name`) = BINARY LOWER('Apple') AND `country` = 'US');

+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------------------------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key                                | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------------------------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | keywords | index | NULL          | index_keywords_on_name_and_country | 777     | NULL | 366519 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------------------------------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
```

I'm using MySQL 5.5.

Any reason why this happens?

And is there a way I can use the index on my query? Or how can change my query and table in order to use the index to speed up the query.

Thanks

Comment: Well, why do you expect, that the index is used? The index is on `name`, not on `BINARY LOWER(name)`.

Comment: @nosid But why index is used when doing `SELECT keywords.id, keywords.name`?

Comment: Indexes will not works for the columns if any function is applied on that column

Comment: @StevenTen: It uses the index, because the index contains all required columns and is probably smaller than the primary table. However, the database still performs a full table scan on the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to do the comparison to `binary lower()`?  This seems like a very odd requirement for keywords.

In any case, you could do this with subqueries:

```
SELECT k.*
FROM (SELECT k.*
      FROM `keywords` k
      WHERE name = 'Apple' and country = 'US'
     ) k
WHERE (BINARY LOWER(`name`) = BINARY LOWER('Apple') AND `country` = 'US');
```

The inner subquery should use the index.  The resulting scan should be on a small subset, so it should be fast.

Comment: The reason for using `binary lower` is for those names that contain accent. For example search for `Lé` will also get `Le` if not using `binary lower`

Comment: @StevenTen . . . I understand.  This just seems unusual that a system would have keywords in a common character set with no language indicator and still want to distinguish by language.  You are probably using `country` as a proxy for language.  In any case, this form of the query should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing the character set (and collation) spoils the use of an index. The optimizer can't rely on the collation you specify alphabetizing strings in the same way they're stored in the index, so therefore it doesn't use the index.

If you use a case-insensitive COLLATION, you don't have to do this BINARY LOWER expression at all.

```
mysql> select 'apple' = 'Apple';
+-------------------+
| 'apple' = 'Apple' |
+-------------------+
|                 1 |
+-------------------+
```

The "ci" suffix in collations indicates case-insensitivity.

```
mysql> show session variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

So just do the simple string comparison (provided you have set the collation order for this table to a ci collation):

```
SELECT keywords.* FROM `keywords` WHERE `name` = 'Apple' AND `country` = 'US');
```

---

Re your comment:

Comparing accented characters depends on the character set and collation.

```
mysql> SELECT 'Lé' = 'le';

mysql> SET NAMES latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;

mysql> select 'lé' = 'Lé';
+---------------+
| 'lé' = 'Lé'   |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+

mysql> select 'lé' = 'Le';
+--------------+
| 'lé' = 'Le'  |
+--------------+
|            0 |
+--------------+
```

I can't find a Unicode collation in MySQL that treat accented characters as different, but preserves case-insensitivity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now the Collation of `name` and `country` is set to `utf8_general_ci`. It can solve the problem for uppercase or downcase. But how about accent? If we search for `Lé`, it will also get `Le`